# React Redux Error the page is displayed before getting the data

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, redux, react-router, effect

I have a problem. I would like to get some data before loading the DOM but I have been running into this error for hours. I have a 200 response on my query but the error persists. After a reload of the page the display is ok.

```
 // redux
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const customers = useSelector((state) => state.customerReducer);

useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(findAllCustomers());
}, [])

  { !isEmpty(Object.values(customers))  && Object.values(customers)[0].map((customer, index) => ...
```

Uncaught TypeError: Object.values(...)[0].map is not a function ...

Thanks for your help.

```
[Array(54)]
  0: (54) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…},


0: Array(54)
  0: {id: 2,, …}
  1: {id: 3,  …}
  2: {id: 4 , …}

//Actions.js
export const findAllCustomers = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('/api/customers')
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({
                type: FIND_ALL_CUSTOMERS, payload:response.data
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error.response))
    }
}


 //CustomersReducer.js

const INITIAL_STATE = [];

function customerReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action)
{
     switch (action.type){
        case 'FIND_NB_CUSTOMERS' : {
            return {
                ...state,
                nbCustomers : action.payload
             }
         }
         case 'FIND_ALL_CUSTOMERS' : {
             return {
                 ...state,
                 customers: action.payload
             }
          }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

 export default customerReducer;

//isEmpty()
export const isEmpty = (value) => {
console.log(value)
return (
    value === undefined ||
    value === null ||
    (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 
       0) ||
        (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0)
    );
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `Object.values(customers)[0]` and not `Object.values(customers)` without the `[0]`?  Is this an array or arrays?

Comment: Why are you mapping index [0]?

Comment: Show us the data stored in `customers`. Without it, all answers are speculative guesswork.

Comment: thanks ...I just updated my post with the data received

Comment: @zero298 The real problem is when I click on the link leading to the customers page, the data does not have time to arrive the page is already built, when I refresh the page then the data is displayed correctly – Cedric Flamain 22 mins ago   Delete

Comment: What is `isEmpty()`? I don't think this is a built in JavaScript function.

Comment: I just updated the code above with the isEmpty () function

Answer (score 2):

Object.values(customers) return an Array and you are trying to access the first index of that array which is probably not an Array anymore.

**Change to:**

```
Object.values(customers).map()
```

Comment: Or maybe it should be `customers.map()`. It's hard to tell without some indication of what `customers` is.

Comment: I couldn't agree more

Comment: @RyanLe The real problem is when I click on the link leading to the customers page, the data does not have time to arrive the page is already built, when I refresh the page then the data is displayed correctly – Cedric Flamain 22 mins ago   Delete

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use `map()` on something that isn't an array. `Object.values(customers)[0]` is an object. However, since `customers` is an array, there is no reason to use `Object.values()` at all. Instead, just map over the array directly with `customers.map()`.

So all together it should be

```
{ customers && customers.map(...) }
```

Comment: The real problem is when I click on the link leading to the customers page, the data does not have time to arrive the page is already built, when I refresh the page then the data is displayed correctly

Comment: @CedricFlamain That's a different question than you posted here. I suggest you start a new question to get help with that problem.

Comment: @CedricFlamain Do the current answers not solve the problem? They should solve the immediate error, but there seems to be another underlying problem that requires a new question with updated code that doesn't cause this error.

Comment: I modified the question the initial problem is caused by the page which is loaded before receiving the data. The question does. can be deleted at this point.

Comment: @CedricFlamain I don't think you can delete the question now that it has answers with votes. You should just post a new question.